# Use property in OSGI component declaration

Tags: liferay, osgi, liferay-7

In my module, in OSGI component declarationIi need to use a property which will be in my portal-ext.properties, like that :

```
@Component(
immediate = true,
property = {
"dispatcher=FORWARD",
"dispatcher=REQUEST",
"servlet-context-name=",
"servlet-filter-name=Detail UC Filter",
"url-pattern=/web/guest/" + PropsUtil.get("myPath") + "/*"
}
```

But i get the compilation error : " The value for annotation attribute Component.property must be a constant expression". How can i do to use a property here?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site - Do not crosspost!

Answer (score 2):

> But i get the compilation error : " The value for annotation attribute Component.property must be a constant expression". How can i do to use a property here?

The entry:

```
"url-pattern=/web/guest/" + PropsUtil.get("myPath") + "/*"
```

is the problem. This is because annotations can only have values that are compile-time constants. Obviously this property is not a compile time constant as its value depends on calling a method.

If you want to supply property values at runtime then you can do this in OSGi using Configuration Admin. All Declarative Services components are configurable by default, using a pid which is either:

- User configured by setting `@Component(configurationPid="foo")`
- User configured by setting `@Component(name="bar")`
- Defaulted using the fully qualified class name of the component implementation

When you supply a configuration dictionary to Configuration Admin which matches the pid for your DS component then it will be bound to the component.

1. Your component properties will be merged with the configuration dictionary (with the configuration overriding the static properties). This can be received by your component using an `@Activate` method
2. If your component is registered as a service then your service properties will also be updated.
3. If your component has a `@Modified` method then these changes will be dynamic, otherwise your component instance will be deactivated and discarded, and a new instance created and activated.

You can force your component not to activate until a configuration has been provided by setting your component's configuration policy. This is useful when you have a property that needs to exist, but can't be known until runtime.

```
@Component(configurationPolicy=ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set any of these properties using a config admin configuration.
So one approach is to have a separate component that writes a configuration for this component.

You can use `configurationPolicy = ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE` to prevent the component to become activated before this configuration is present.

Another approach is to use a component factory. See [this blog from Scott](http://sully6768.blogspot.de/2012/09/declarative-services-with-karaf-part-4.html).